# change AASM state through edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, aasm

I'm using AASM to manage states in my User model.

I want to change the status through the edit action.

To do this I'm using the method User.aasm_states_for_select in my form
to populate the select input for states.
When I hit the button commit all the changes are saved, including the
state name. But the AASM event for that state is not called, it is
happening because only the field status has changed and the event method
has not been called.

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the only solution there is to find event from state name and apply it directly. Something like

```
STATE_MAPPING = {
  'state_name' => :event_name
}

#...

def update
  user.public_send(state_event) if state_event
  user.update permitted_attributes

  #...
end

# ...

def state_event
  state = params.require(:user).permit(:state)[:state]
  STATE_MAPPING[state]
end

def permitted_attributes
  @params.require(:user).permit #attributes without state
end
```

Too much hustle tbh, but to my knowledge there is no other solution available

Comment: should I use state_machine gem for this?

Comment: @MihirKumarThakur I believe aasm is better. At least in a project I was working on, `state_machine` was replaced with `aasm` as it was better maintained by that time

Comment: A lot of what the state machine does could just be expressed through validations so maybe you woudlnt need the state machine at all?